# Suppress warnings using .NET Core CLI task (DotNetCoreCLI@2) in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli

Trying to suppress warnings in Azure DevOps pipeline using .NET Core CLI task (DotNetCoreCLI@2), but getting the following error:

MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: --noWarn:MSB3277

Here is an example of the code, which is similar to how the switch is used in a couple of posts I found related to msbuild cli reference:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Release Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '${{ parameters.solutionPath }}'
    arguments: --configuration Release --noWarn:MSB3277
```

I have tried lowercase --nowarn as well, but still no luck, so any help with this issue would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your support,

Terry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please use `/nowarn:msb3277`

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Release Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '${{ parameters.solutionPath }}'
    arguments: --configuration Release /nowarn:msb3277
```

Comment: BINGO!  Didn't even think to try / format DOH!  Thought the -- format was required. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Terry Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score 5):

To remove all messages apart from errors `/clp:ErrorsOnly` can do the trick, for example `dotnet build /clp:ErrorsOnly`.

In general this is not a good idea to hide warning messages but can be handy in certain situations where a third party library is clogging the CI build logs.